# Correct way to use javascript timeOut()

Tags: javascript, timeout

For example if i was to format my code as followed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeout;
    function auto() {
        $.ajax({
                url: "functions/ajax.php",
                data: "func=auto",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                       $.each(data.search, function (i, v) {
                               console.log('Success ' + v);
                       });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                       console.log('Error ' + jqXHR);
                }
        });
     }

    function start() {
    timeout = setTimeout('auto()', 2000);
    }

    function stop(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
}
</script>
```

Would it matter that my `var timeout` is not defined by a value ? since the actual timeout is not even processing, it's running the function `auto()` once, then stops

Comment: I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Your code looks fine, what's the issue?

Comment: the timeout isn't processing, it runs the code wrong and then doesn't "auto" run again after 2 seconds

Comment: (For reference, btw, `setTimeout('some javascript', time)` has been a broken way of doing things for like a decade.  You could say `setTimeout(auto, 2000)` instead.  Or even `setTimeout(function() { /* all the code in your auto() function! */ }, 2000)`, and not even have to name the function...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use quotes in the setTimeout (I'm not sure but I believe that calls `eval()`), just pass in the function by reference: `setTimeout(auto, 2000)`;

Second of all, JavaScript is a dynamically typed language, which means variables don't have a fixed type, and they can change depending on the circumstances, therefore your code is perfectly valid.

Lastly, if you don't plan to abort the timeout whilst it's counting, you don't need to clear it, as it will disappear after being executed.

Comment: Thanks for this information, but my code isn't activating the setTimeout for the function, it runs the code once and then stops

Comment: You're probably looking for setInterval, just replace your setTimeout with setInterval, and it will repeat that function every 2 seconds. setTimeout only fires once.

Comment: as @MattDiamant said, if you need to run it every 2000ms and not just once after 2000ms, use `setInterval(auto,2000)` instead. However, be careful, you DO need to clear an interval to make it stop, or it will run indefinitely.

Comment: That's perfect ! you're great guys with amazing explanations that cleared everything up !

Comment: Just one little detail, if you are looking for an specific interval between the end of one loop and the beginning of the next one, it's more accurate to use setTimeout at the end of the function, instead of setInterval. In this case, however, with 2000ms, it does not make any difference.